# Проблема с алфавитной сортировкой строк в Android и буквой Ё

Tags: java, android, kotlin, unicode, icu

Задача: есть список имён - нужно разбить на группы по первой букве: А, Б, В, Г, Д, Е, Ё, Ж, ...

Я попробовал `String.compareTo` и `java.text.Collator` но не нашел работающего варианта (чтобы сортировал строго по порядку букв в русском алфавите)

---

`String.compareTo` - сравнивает не по порядку букв в алфавите (несмотря на то что в описании указан lexicographic ordering)

```
val list = listOf("аа", "яя", "жж", "еж", "ёж", "ежовый")
val sorted = list.sortedWith(Comparator { a, b -> a.compareTo(b, ignoreCase = true) })
println(sorted.toString())
```

> result: [аа, еж, ежовый, жж, яя, **ёж**]

---

java.text.Collator - не нашел варианта при котором Ё не смешивалась бы с Е

```
val list = listOf("аа", "яя", "жж", "еж", "ёж", "ежовый")
val collator = java.text.Collator.getInstance().apply { 
    decomposition = Collator.NO_DECOMPOSITION
    strength = Collator.TERTIARY
}
val sorted = list.sortedWith(Comparator { a, b -> collator.compare(a, b) })
println(sorted.toString())
```

> result: [аа, еж, **ёж**, **ежовый**, жж, яя]

---

Правильно ли я понимаю что в Android нет сортировки по алфавиту и нужно сочинять свою ?

Comment: В случае Ё - да, придется сочинять свою, либо сортировать смешивая с Е, а потом дополнительно на Е и Ё сортировать. И дело не в Андроиде. Если уж на то пошло, Вы используете стандартную библиотеку Java. Буква Ё криво расположена в Unicode, так что это касается почти всех языков программирования.

Comment: Т.е. в описании String.compareTo сказано `lexicographic ordering`, а на самом деле - бессмысленное нечто основанное на порядке букв в Unicode. Получается это баг реализации либо неправильное описание одного из самых важных методов для строк ?

Comment: Суть в том, что _почти все_ символы в Unicode расположены в лексикографическом порядке. Но некоторые попали не на свои места. Точно знаю про ё в русском, сдвоенную s в немецком. Кажется, с й у нас еще проблемы бывают.

Comment: По идее `Collator.SECONDARY` должен правильно отрабатывать разницу между и `е` и `ё` - ссылки на то, что они в разных концах таблицы Unicode конечно же несостоятельны

Comment: Я вот тоже думал что должен, а по факту оно работает не так, и вообще получается что через Collator нельзя получить именно алфавитный порядок, собственно в этом и вопрос - есть ли прямой способ получить алфавит в правильном порядке стандартными средствами (без костылей и создания константы с правильным порядком букв)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Коллеги,

Не там по-моему ищете:

1) Android здесь не причем, корень в Java конечно же

2) Надо все же таки явно указывать на локаль, иначе будет взята локаль по умолчанию, которая может быть какой угодно:

```
Locale   locale = Locale.RU;
Collator collator = Collator.getInstance(locale);
```

3) Чтобы различать `е` и `ё` надо задавать флаг коллатора как `SECONDARY` согласно мануалу:

> Collator strength value. When set, only SECONDARY and above differences are considered significant during comparison. The assignment of strengths to language features is locale dependant. A common example is for different accented forms of the same base letter ("a" vs "ä") to be considered a SECONDARY difference.

И только потом уже запускать компарацию.

3) Если уж совсем неймётся, то можно применить `RuleBasedCollator` для `ё`, и обойтись без велосипедов:

```
String yoRule = "< е < ё";
RuleBasedCollator ruleBasedCollator =
    new RuleBasedCollator(yoRule);
```

И напоследок, не надо думать, что наш русский язык какой-то супер особенный, есть языки и позаковыристее, в комитете Unicode отнюдь не дураки сидят и давно уже разработали [корректный алгоритм сравнения](http://unicode.org/reports/tr10/), на основе которой и работает `Collation` в Java

**Update**

```
val list = listOf("аа", "яя", "жж", "еж", "ежп", "ёж", "ёжя", "ежовый")
val yoRule = "< а < б < в < г < д < е < ё < ж < з < и < й < к < л < м < н < о < п < р < с < т < у < ф < х < ц < ч < ш < щ < ъ < ы < ь < я < ю < я"
val ruleBasedCollator = RuleBasedCollator(yoRule)
val sorted = list.sortedWith(Comparator { a, b -> ruleBasedCollator.compare(a, b) })
println(sorted.toString())
```

> [аа, еж, ежовый, ежп, ёж, ёжя, жж, яя]

Так работает?

Comment: `val list = listOf("аа", "яя", "жж", "еж", "ёж", "ежовый")
for (decompositionValue in 0..2) { // NO_DECOMPOSITION..FULL_DECOMPOSITION
    for (strengthValue in 0..3) { // PRIMARY..IDENTICAL
        val collator = java.text.Collator.getInstance().apply {
            decomposition = decompositionValue
            strength = strengthValue
        }
        val sorted = list.sortedWith(Comparator { a, b -> collator.compare(a, b) })
        println("[$decompositionValue,$strengthValue] -> $sorted\n")
    }
}`
всегда выдаёт [аа, еж, ёж, ежовый, жж, яя]

Comment: кроме того также падает при попытке использования `FULL_DECOMPOSITION`

Comment: см. апдейт, только надо исправить правила для русского начиная от `а` до `я`

Comment: в kotlin repl (Android Studio) - вроде правильно:
`[аа, еж, ежовый, ежп, ёж, ёжя, жж, яя]`

но на девайсе - ему похоже всё равно на правила - сравнивает по unicode:
`System.out: fullrule -> [аа, еж, ёж, ежовый, ежп, ёжя, жж, яя]`

Comment: был неправ, на девайсе тоже работает, только нужно правильно написать yoRule и учесть Uppercase: `System.out: fullrule -> [aa, bb, cc, аа, еж, ежовый, ёж, жж, яя, Аа, Еж, Ежовый, Ёж, Жж, Яя]`

Answer (score 1):

Как костыльный вариант могу предложить такой способ:

```
val l = listOf("аа", "яя", "жж", "еж", "ёж", "ежовый")
val sorted = l.sortedWith(Comparator { a, b -> a.compareTo(b, ignoreCase = true) }) //сортируем стандартно
val indexE = sorted.indexOfFirst { it.toLowerCase().firstOrNull() == 'ё' } 
val result = sorted.subList(0, indexE).toMutableList() //получаем отсортированный список слов, начинающихся НЕ с буквы Ё
val eList = sorted.subList(indexE, sorted.size) //получаем отсортированный список слов, начинающихся с Ё
val insertPos = sorted.indexOfLast { it.toLowerCase().firstOrNull() == 'е' }
result.addAll(insertPos + 1, eList) //вставляем слова, начинающиеся с Ё за словами, начинающимися с Е
println(result.toString())
```

Результат вроде правильный, но, понятно, хреново выглядит))

Сортировка будет корректной только для первых букв, вторые и прочие - ё будет считаться самой последней буквой алфавита.

Answer (score 0):

Пока не придумал ничего лучше чем изменить `String.compareToIgnoreCase` таким образом:

```
val CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER_RU = kotlin.Comparator { s1: String, s2: String ->
    val n1 = s1.length
    val n2 = s2.length
    val min = Math.min(n1, n2)
    for (i in 0 until min) {
        var c1 = s1[i]
        var c2 = s2[i]
        if (c1 != c2) {
            c1 = Character.toUpperCase(c1)
            c2 = Character.toUpperCase(c2)
            if (c1 != c2) {
                c1 = Character.toLowerCase(c1)
                c2 = Character.toLowerCase(c2)
                if (c1 != c2) {
                    // No overflow because of numeric promotion
                    return@Comparator when {
                        c1 == 'ё' ->
                            if (c2 == 'е') 1 else 'е' - c2

                        c2 == 'ё' ->
                            if (c1 == 'е') -1 else c1 - 'е'

                        else ->
                            c1 - c2
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return@Comparator n1 - n2
}
val list = listOf("аа", "яя", "жж", "еж", "ёж", "ежовый", 
                  "Аа", "Яя", "Жж", "ЕЖ", "Ёж", "Ежовый")
val sorted = list.sortedWith(CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER_RU)
```

> result: [аа, Аа, еж, ЕЖ, ежовый, Ежовый, ёж, Ёж, жж, Жж, яя, Яя]

---

### Update:

решение от [@barmaley-red-star](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1117549/190325) на основе `java.text.RuleBasedCollator`

```
val list = listOf("0", "9", "1", 
                  "аа", "яя", "жж", "еж", "ёж", "ежовый",
                  "Аа", "Яя", "Жж", "Еж", "Ёж", "Ежовый", 
                  "aa", "bb", "cc")
val yoRule = "& а < б < в < г < д < е < ё < ж < з < и < й "+
             "< к < л < м < н < о < п < р < с < т < у < ф "+
             "< х < ц < ч < ш < щ < ъ < ы < ь < э < ю < я"
val ruleBasedCollator = java.text.RuleBasedCollator(yoRule)
val locale = Locale("ru")
val sorted = list.sortedWith(Comparator { a, b -> 
    ruleBasedCollator.compare(a.toLowerCase(locale), b.toLowerCase(locale)) 
})
println("RuleBasedCollator -> $sorted")
```

> RuleBasedCollator -> [0, 1, 9, aa, bb, cc, аа, Аа, еж, Еж, ежовый, Ежовый, ёж, Ёж, жж, Жж, яя, Яя]